# Meteor requestPermissions

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api, meteor, github-api, user-permissions

Hey guys actually i got two question.

1.Im tying to get user info here is a list of what info i want (using facebook API):
user_likes, friends_about_me, user_birthday, email, user_location, user_work_history, read_friendlists, friends_groups, user_groups

here is my code for that:

```
Template.user_loggedout.events({ 
    "click #fb":function(e,tmp){
      Meteor.loginWithFacebook({
        requestPermissions : 
        ['user_likes',
        'friends_about_me',
        'user_birthday',
        'email',
        'user_location',
        'user_work_history',
        'read_friendlists',
        'friends_groups',
        'user_groups']
      },function (err){
         if(err){
          console.log("error when login with facebook " + err);
        } else {
          console.log("login with facebook succeeded");
        }
      });
    },
})
```

but my i ends up creating a user object with just some of the fields (user JSON object from mongoDB, i inserted "xxx" at some fields just for security):

```
{
    "createdAt" : 1378842117154,
    "_id" : "mW7urf5yZPCm6HhNK",
    "services" : {
        "facebook" : {
            "accessToken" : "xxxx",
            "expiresAt" : 1383945305007,
            "id" : "xxxxxx",
            "email" : "xxxx",
            "name" : "Boaz",
            "first_name" : "Boaz",
            "last_name" : "xxx",
            "link" : "https://www.facebook.com/xxxx",
            "username" : "boazmier",
            "gender" : "male",
            "locale" : "he_IL"
        },
        "resume" : {
            "loginTokens" : [
                {
                    "token" : "TcLnp9GSbDasNZNCj",
                    "when" : 1378842117154
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "profile" : {
        "name" : "Boaz xxxx"
    }
}
```

clearly you can see that there is no record for friends_list, user_birthday and much more.

second question:
same thing with github - i requset this: user, public_repo, avatar_url, gist 
but end up with:

```
{
    "createdAt" : 1378843359664,
    "_id" : "pJGwTepYe2Ps7hhnS",
    "services" : {
        "github" : {
            "id" : xxxx,
            "accessToken" : "xxxxx",
            "email" : "xxxxx",
            "username" : "boazhoch"
        },
        "resume" : {
            "loginTokens" : [
                {
                    "token" : "hbNLcuC85MKwBJBfb",
                    "when" : 1378843359664
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "profile" : {
        "name" : "xxxx"
    }
}
```

so i end up with no avatar but when changing my code on server to:

```
Accounts.onCreateUser(function(options,user){
    var accessToken = user.services.github.accessToken,result,profile;

    result = Meteor.http.get("https://api.github.com/user", {
        params: {
            access_token: accessToken
        }
    });

    if(result.error){
        throw result.error
    }

    profile = _.pick(result.data,
        "login",
        "name",
        "avatar_url",
        "url",
        "company",
        "blog",
        "location",
        "email",
        "bio",
        "html_url");

    user.profile = profile;

    return user;
});
```

my user object get the avatar_url why is that? i know that meteor ships out with Account.createUser and by doing onCreateUser im overriding it but then, what is the porpse of requestPermissions? also i can have only one Account.onCreateUser function, so  how do i make this function request different data from each service? ( i want to include facebook,google,github,twitter and meetup)

Comment: You are right that many of the fields you are requesting are not being saved in there by Meteor at login. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want the data to be available **on the client** to anyone with JS skills? If so, on saving things to the user record:  The easiest thing to do would be to add any new information to the profile object, possibly grouped under a facebook object when from facebook.  The profile object already is **all** published to the client.  http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_user

```
user.profile.prefs.color = 'red'
```

To keep it confidential, as you find things that should not make it to the client, write and read them from routines on the server.  See

```
Meteor.call()
```

You can find code for how to get more data in the user record from the server to the client and back, where you essentially publish more.  I wouldn't worry until there is a reason the profile object is insufficient.